# Phantomjs page.evaluate and q deferred issue

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, q

I am trying to use "Q" promise library with PhantomJS and the below code does not work.

```
app.evaluate_page=function(page){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    console.log("Before the page evaluation");
    page.evaluate(function(){
        deferred.resolve(page);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

**Following is the error**

```
Before the page evaluation
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: deferred
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3
```

Looks like it is not able to find deferred variable defined in the outer scope and that is strange. The same kind of code works with other methods which have the call back like page.open method.

**The following code just works as expected and not sure why the above code does not.**

```
app.openPage = function(options){
  var deferred = q.defer();
  page.open(options.url,function(status){
      if(status!=="success"){
          deferred.reject(new Error("Page could not be loaded at "+ options.url ));
      }
      else {
          deferred.resolve(page);
      }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `page.evaluate()` is synchronous.

Comment: Yes.I want page.evaluate to be synchronous.

Comment: It is, so why do you need `q`?

Comment: Oh ok. I was not sure about that.Let me use it synchronously and see how it works. Thanks,

Comment: Is page.open synchronous too?

Comment: No, it is not. The function that you pass into `page.open` is a callback. The function for `page.evaluate` is the function that should be executed in the page context and not a callback.

Answer (score 0):

`page.evaluate` runs in the browser process, and cannot access your variables.

You have the `page` variable synchronously, so you have no need for promises here.

Answer (score 0):

As @slaks mentions it, the `page.evaluate` callback function runs in a sandboxed environment.

The [official documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) clearly states that `page.evaluate`:

> Evaluates the given function in the context of the web page. The
>   execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom
>   object and it can’t probe its own setting.

Yet you can pass arguments in and out but as the [official documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) states it:

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must
>   be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be
>   serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

As of now (october 2016), digging deeper into the subject, this seems to be an open issue.

1. there's an open issue on github about enabling promises with `page.evaluate` : [Waitfor support for Promise pattern · Issue #14166 · ariya/phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14166)
2. there's an experimental api to enable a callback function from the web page context : [onCallback | PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html)
3. the official method for waiting for a web page to be ready is to extend the [waitfor.js example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js)

I use a personnal blend of the 3rd method.

This is my `main.js` file:

```
'use strict';

var wasSuccessful = phantom.injectJs('./lib/waitFor.js');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://foo.com', function(status) {
  if (status === 'success') {
    page.includeJs('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
      waitFor(function() {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
          if ('complete' === document.readyState) {
            return true;
          }

          return false;
        });
      }, function() {
        var fooText = page.evaluate(function() {
          return $('#foo').text();
        });

        phantom.exit();
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error');
    phantom.exit(1);
  }
});
```

And the `lib/waitFor.js` file (which is just a copy and paste of the `waifFor()` function from the phantomjs [`waitfor.js` example](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)):

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    // console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condi>
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
}
```

This method is not asynchronous but at least am I assured that all the resources were loaded before I try using them.